# Android ListView appearing underneath Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put a ListView below a Toolbar (that has a Navigation Drawer). Currently, the ListView is appearing underneath the Toolbar rather than below it (see picture). How would I fix this?

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `FrameLayout` to a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` as an attribute.

As a side note you should be using `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`